# My load on scroll doesn't work on IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery

IT's all in the title, the loading on scroll is working fine on chrome and FF but not in IE 8

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){
var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
    openFromButton()
    } 
  lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

It seems that the problem comes from scrollTop

Comment: IT does nothing, when I scroll data is not loaded,I'm using jquery-1.11.1. I think it's from scrollTop which always 0 when it comes to IE8

Answer (score 0):

Try document instead of window.

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(document).scroll(function(){
var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
    openFromButton()
    } 
  lastScrollTop = st;
});
```